# Как правильно читать json файл в C#

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Ребят, нашел данный код, но есть проблема в том, что код читается по "прямой" ссылке, которая после билда в Unity не работает. Как можно исправить код, чтобы он работал?
public class DS4

```
{
    // Gyroscope
    public static ButtonControl gyroX = null;
    public static ButtonControl gyroY = null;
    public static ButtonControl gyroZ = null;

    public static Gamepad controller = null;

    public static Gamepad getConroller(string layoutFile = null)
    {
        // Read layout from JSON file
        string layout = File.ReadAllText(layoutFile == null ? "Assets/Script/customLayout.json" : layoutFile);

        // Overwrite the default layout
        InputSystem.RegisterLayoutOverride(layout, "DualShock4GamepadHID");

        var ds4 = Gamepad.current;
        DS4.controller = ds4;
        bindControls(DS4.controller);
        return DS4.controller;
    }

    private static void bindControls(Gamepad ds4)
    {
        gyroX = ds4.GetChildControl<ButtonControl>("gyro X 14");
        gyroY = ds4.GetChildControl<ButtonControl>("gyro Y 16");
        gyroZ = ds4.GetChildControl<ButtonControl>("gyro Z 18");
    }

    public static Quaternion getRotation(float scale = 1)
    {
        float x = processRawData(gyroX.ReadValue()) * scale;
        float y = processRawData(gyroY.ReadValue()) * scale;
        float z = -processRawData(gyroZ.ReadValue()) * scale;
        return Quaternion.Euler(x, y, z);
    }

    private static float processRawData(float data)
    {
        return data > 0.5 ? 1 - data : -data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как читать текст после билда: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html

Как парсить json: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 0):

Создай лучше [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) описывыющий туже модель, как этот `json` для удобного редактирования и задайте на него ссылку в инспекторе для вашего класса.

Через [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) его легко превратить в `Json` и скормить методу `RegisterLayoutOverride`.

ПланБ: `public TextAsset MyJson;`.

В любом случае, ссылку на файл задавайте в инспекторе.

Comment: Проблема в том, что этот json код хранит в себе данные с датчиков от геймпада DualShock4. Разве это можно сделать под ScriptableObject?

Comment: В вашем вопросе это просто файл который лежит в каталоге. Тогда вопрос в том, как вы его получаете, его можно запросить у фреймворка? Нужно ли его вообще хранить?